# Hi, how can we add a reply recipient to emails send to contacts?

Tags: email

how can we add a reply recipient to emails send to contacts assuming they would do reply not reply all.
Our sales folks are sending some custom emails to contacts , the replies to which our support teams would like to be recipient as well. We are on Outlook if that helps..

Comment: Are you using the Salesforce to Outlook connector at all or is it standalone?

Comment: it is standalone

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below steps:

1. Create a group email address which will have a list of users who
   wants to receive the email.
2. Create a Org wide email address in Salesforce which will be that email address.
3. Set the reply to of that Emails to contact to the Org Wide email address.

The Contact would still be replying to a single email address but it will now go to a group of user.